# Connection Unstable - Two routers connected via switch

Tags: router, modem, intranet

My network has got slightly complicated.

I have a (D-Link ADSL Modem + Router), which connects to the ISP. From there a cable runs to 8 port switch. From the switch another cable runs to my rooms wifi router.

Now the problem is weird. Although I am able to connect to all computers in the network, both the routers and the internet, it lives short. The connection is very unstable. I am getting " Request Timed Out " when I try to ping even the root router. Sometimes local network works but internet doesn't work.

**Modem is a D-Link DSL-2730U** : (192.168.1.1) DHCP enabled

**Switch** is a 8 Port D-Link unmanaged switch.

**WiFi router is an old Teracom modem+router** : (192.168.1.100) DHCP server disabled. DHCP relay is set to DSL-2730U's address.

Comment: Please provide a short summary of the configuration you've got on both the router and the wifi AP. If the switch is managed - which I don't believe - you will also want to look into that.

To me, this sounds a bit like you've got DHCP servers on both the router and the AP running.

Comment: @Patrick R, +1 for the two DHCP servers on network. I'll bet that that's the root cause.

Comment: @PatrickR. Updated post. !

Comment: Not sure you need the DHCP relay enabled. Your network is small enough and not segmented to require it...

Comment: @BigChris Disabled that, still the same.

Comment: So, how does the DHCP Lease you get look like after disabling the DHCP relay?

Comment: @PatrickR. same as it was. it's still unstable http://i.imgur.com/1iWPvyc.png

Comment: I meant the lease itself. Do you get the right gateway and DNS? just to make sure the teracom device really doesn't answer dhcp queries.

Comment: @PatrickR. Yes, the dns and gateway are borrowed correct, being set to the modem ip.

Comment: I understand that only clients on the AP wifi are having trouble, is that right?